# XSLT: grouping by value

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to group the below xml by using xslt when integer = '4' and then loop through each dict, check whether the  each element has integer = 5  and then variable should be set to pass only  .And also if any of integer value is 7 and status to be fail.

Any suggestion please ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>All Samples</key>
<array>
<dict>
<key>LogType</key>
<string>Start</string>
<key>Message</key>
<string>START:Certificate and Genre filter tests</string>
<key>Timestamp</key>
<date>2012-06-25T10:49:02Z</date>
<key>Type</key>
<integer>4</integer>
</dict>
<dict>
<key>LogType</key>
<string>Pass</string>
<key>Message</key>
<string>Navigation title bar should contain genre in card view : ACTION &amp; ADVENTURE</string>
<key>Timestamp</key>
<date>2012-06-25T10:49:13Z</date>
<key>Type</key>
<integer>5</integer>
</dict>
<dict>
<key>LogType</key>
<string>Pass</string>
<key>Message</key>
<string>START: certificate tests filter tests</string>
<key>Timestamp</key>
<date>2012-06-25T10:49:02Z</date>
<key>Type</key>
<integer>4</integer>
</dict>
<dict>
<key>LogType</key>
<string>Pass</string>
<key>Message</key>
<string>Navigation title bar should contain genre in card view : ACTION &amp; ADVENTURE</string>
<key>Timestamp</key>
<date>2012-06-25T10:49:13Z</date>
<key>Type</key>
<integer>5</integer>
</dict>
<dict>
<key>LogType</key>
<string>Fail</string>
<key>Message</key>
<string>Navigation title bar should contain genre in card view : ACTION &amp; ADVENTURE</string>
<key>Timestamp</key>
<date>2012-06-25T10:49:13Z</date>
<key>Type</key>
<integer>7</integer>
</dict>
</array>
</dict>
</plist>

expected result  in table view with format


| Test Name | test steps |   Test result|
START : GENRE FILTER TEST |    | FAIL ( background color to red)
test step1 | Navigation title bar should contain genre in card view | PASS
test step2 | Navigation title bar should contain genre in card view | FAIL

|START : certificate tests filter tests |    | PASS ( background color to green)
|test step 1 | Navigation title bar should contain genre in card view | PASS
```

thanks,
bob

Comment: I don't see "below code" that you say you tried with - where is it? Also, could you please provide an Xml example of what the output should look like?

Comment: Totally unclear. What the heck does " split the xml" mean? Please show your expected output, both in pass and fail cases.

Comment: Please indicate whether you are able to use XSLT 2.0. Grouping problems are much easier to solve with 2.0 than 1.0.

Comment: i want to use xslt version 1.0 only because of Xcode UI Automation instrument limitation

Comment: I have corrected the XML sample because it was not well-formed (the 'array' and first 'dict' element were not closed). You might want to double-check it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this could be to define a key to look up **dict** elements by the first preceding-sibling with integer = 4

```
<xsl:key 
   name="test" 
   match="dict[integer[preceding-sibling::key[1]='Type']!=4]" 
  use="generate-id(
       preceding-sibling::dict[integer[preceding-sibling::key[1]='Type']=4][1]
    )" />
```

Then you would start by matching all the **dict** elements with integer = 4

```
<xsl:apply-templates 
   select="dict
     [key='All Samples']/array/dict[integer[preceding-sibling::key[1]='Type']=4]" />
```

And then you could write a template a template for which a 'Fail' element exists, and handle them accordingly

```
<xsl:template 
   match="dict
     [key('test', generate-id())[string[preceding-sibling::key[1]='LogType']='Fail']]">
```

All other matching **dict** elements would be success elements.

And then to output the results on each individual tests, you could just look them up in the key

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('test', generate-id())" mode="results" />
```

Note the **mode** is needed, because you will have multiple templates matching **dict** elements, and so you need to distinguish between them.

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:key name="test" match="dict[integer[preceding-sibling::key[1]='Type']!=4]" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::dict[integer[preceding-sibling::key[1]='Type']=4][1])"/>

   <xsl:template match="plist">
      <xsl:variable name="dicts" select="dict[key='All Samples']/array/dict[integer[preceding-sibling::key[1]='Type']=4]"/>       
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td>
               <xsl:text>Test Name</xsl:text>
            </td>
            <td>
               <xsl:text>Test Steps</xsl:text>
            </td>
            <td>
               <xsl:text>Test Result</xsl:text>
            </td>
         </tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$dicts"/>
      </table>
      <xsl:variable name="fails" select="count($dicts[key('test', generate-id())[string[preceding-sibling::key[1]='LogType']='Fail']])" />
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('total tests passed = ', count($dicts) - $fails)" />
      <br />
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('total tests failed = ', $fails)" /> 
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="dict[key('test', generate-id())[string[preceding-sibling::key[1]='LogType']='Fail']]">
      <xsl:call-template name="dict">
         <xsl:with-param name="type" select="'Fail'"/>
         <xsl:with-param name="colour" select="'#FF0000'" />
      </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="dict" name="dict">
      <xsl:param name="type" select="'Pass'"/>
      <xsl:param name="colour" select="'#00FF00'" />
      <tr>
         <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="string[preceding-sibling::key[1]='Message']"/>
         </td>
         <td>
         </td>
         <td style="background-color:{$colour}">
            <xsl:value-of select="$type"/>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('test', generate-id())" mode="results" />
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="dict" mode="results">
      <tr>
         <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('Test Step ', position())" />
         </td>
         <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="string[preceding-sibling::key[1]='Message']"/>
         </td>
         <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="string[preceding-sibling::key[1]='LogType']"/>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your XML sample, the following is output

```
<table>
  <tr>
     <td>Test Name</td>
     <td>Test Steps</td>
     <td>Test Result</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>START:Certificate and Genre filter tests</td>
     <td/>
     <td style="background-color:#00FF00">Pass</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>Test Step 1</td>
     <td>Navigation title bar should contain genre in card view : ACTION &amp; ADVENTURE</td>
     <td>Pass</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>START: certificate tests filter tests</td>
     <td/>
     <td style="background-color:#FF0000">Fail</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>Test Step 1</td>
     <td>Navigation title bar should contain genre in card view : ACTION &amp; ADVENTURE</td>
     <td>Pass</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>Test Step 2</td>
     <td>Navigation title bar should contain genre in card view : ACTION &amp; ADVENTURE</td>
     <td>Fail</td>
  </tr>
</table>
total tests passed = 1 
<br/>
total tests failed = 1
```

Do note the used of a named-template to make use of shared code for the 'success' and 'fail' rows.

Comment: thanks for reply, Also i need to count the no of tests passed and failed .   expected o/p total tests passed = 1 total tests failed = 1

Comment: I left that as an exercise for the reader... But anyway, I have now amended my answer to show the total rows.

Comment: hi tim, please refer the expected result in main section

Comment: I've updated my answer, but in the future can you be careful about amending your expected output after a question has been answered. There is nothing wrong with asking a new question if needed. Thanks.

Comment: Since i did not have more space in 'Add comment" section, so updated in the main section. Many thanks for solution.

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to 'accept' any answer that solves the problem, as this will help other users who come across this question to know what the solution was.

Comment: thanks, if i want to have an option expand and collapse  at <td START:Certificate and Genre filter tests /> that should expand or collapse the test steps underneath only and same for all remaining elements in the table

Comment: i need to filter the test steps results only when LogType = Pass or fail.
<xsl:template match="dict" mode="results">
<xsl:variable name="result" select="string[preceding-sibling::key[1]='LogType']" />
        <xsl:if test ="$result = Pass|Fail">
      <tr>
         <td>
            <b><xsl:value-of select="concat('Step ', position())" /></b>
         </td>
          
         <td align="center">
            <xsl:value-of select="string[preceding-sibling::key[1]='Message']"/>

Comment: As I mentioned above, if you have new requirements that were not in the original question, feel free to ask a new question.

Comment: I could able to achieve the pass or fail but not able to not able to reset the position index . please see the amended script

Comment: hi tim, as per your suggestion i have a posted new question "Extended : XLST group by value"  thanks bob